# Is there a way to split a line more than once in a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this text file called log.txt.

```
1.a  Receiver Type            : REC-1
     Satellite System         : GPS
     Serial Number            : A123

1.b  Receiver Type            : REC-2
     Satellite System         : GPS
     Serial Number            : B456

1.c  Receiver Type            : REC-3
     Satellite System         : GPS
     Serial Number            : C789
```

I am able to just print the values after the colon ':' for 'Satellite System' and 'Serial Number'. But I can't do the same for 'Receiver Type' due to the 3 characters in front of the 'Receiver Type' line. Any way I can do this? Is there a way to split a line more than once? Completely new to Python. So anything that will help me get the ball rolling would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is the code I currently have that prints just the values of 'Satellite System' and 'Serial Number' after the colon.

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as Log:
    for line in Log:
        if line.split(':')[0].strip() == 'Satellite System':
            sat_sys = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print sat_sys

        if line.split(':')[0].strip() == 'Serial Number':
            ser_num = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print ser_num
```

Comment: You could do `if "Receiver Type" in line `do your stuff`, elif "Satellite System" in line `do another stuff` elif "Serial Number" in line `do another stuff` else `default stuff`. Won't this work?

Answer (score 0):

It is the .strip() that messes things up and not the .split(":"), but you can do it like this:

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as Log:
    for line in Log:
        header = line.split(':')[0]
        if 'Satellite System' in header:
            sat_sys = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print sat_sys
        elif 'Serial Number' in header:
            ser_num = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print ser_num
        elif 'Receiver Type' in header:
            rec_typ = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print rec_typ
```

Comment: Perfect :). Thank you, I'll work around with what you answered.